# How to install Python pip on Nixos?

Tags: python, nixos, nix, nixpkgs

I can't seem to find the appropriate package that install's `pip` on Nixos?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pip` is available as a package on NixOS. For example, for the default Python interpreter, the attribute is `python.pkgs.pip`.

Comment: Trying to do `nix-env --install --attr nixpkgs.python.pkgs.pip` produces the following output for me: _installing 'python2.7-pip-20.3.4' [...] error: Package ‘python-2.7.18.7’ in /nix/store/0z1350wf56r5yydpqv89q9g3a26i8565-nixpkgs/nixpkgs/pkgs/development/interpreters/python/cpython/2.7/default.nix:330 is marked as insecure, refusing to evaluate."_

Answer (score 6):

Check the package availability:

```
$ nix-env -qaP '.*pip.*'
```

Install the desired version e,g:

```
$ nix-env -i python3.7-pip-19.0.3
```

Nix Package Manager Guide : [Chapter 19. Main Commands](https://nixos.org/releases/nix/nix-1.9/manual/#ch-main-commands)

Answer (score 1):

Try using this command `python -m ensurepip --default-pip`, after the installation is complete you can update it to the latest version.

Comment: Trying to do this gives the following error: _"error: externally-managed-environment — This environment is externally managed — This command has been disabled as it tries to modify the immutable `/nix/store` filesystem. — To use Python with Nix and nixpkgs, have a look at the online documentation: <https://nixos.org/manual/nixpkgs/stable/#python>."_

Answer (score 0):

https://nixos.wiki/wiki/Python#pip

Essentially install pip via virtualenv

Comment: While this link may be a good reference, a good Answer here at Stack Exchange will incorporate the actual steps required.